# Injecting Retrofit using Hilt

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt

I am new to Hilt and have never use dagger properly. I get the following error.

```
[Dagger/MissingBinding] retrofit2.Retrofit cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an 
@Provides-annotated method.
```

I have annotated my provideRetrofit Method with @provides and have installed it in Application Component. I want to inject it in my main activity and have used the inject annotation there. I tried installing it in activity component but still same result.

**Here is my Retrofit Module.**

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
class RetrofitModule {

@Singleton
@Provides
fun provideGson(): Gson {
    return GsonBuilder().create()
}

@Singleton
@Provides
fun provideRetrofit (gson: Gson): Retrofit{
   return Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("Base Url")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
        .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava3CallAdapterFactory.create()).build()
}
}
```

In my Main Activity I have written this to inject it.

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

@Inject lateinit var retrofit: Retrofit
```

Comment: Can you post your Activity code?

Comment: @iamanbansal as mentioned I inject it in the main activity . I have added the line where I inject it.

Comment: You need to add Activity class declaration code by any change haven't you forget to add `@AndroidEntryPoint` annotion to Activity ?

Comment: Nope I have added that @ADM

Comment: What about Application class? Have you used annotation `@HiltAndroidApp`?

Comment: @Thracian Yeah, I also added it to my manifest.

Comment: Yes check your `application` class too

Comment: Not in manifest, in your Application class you should use `@HiltAndroidApp`? Have you used it?

Comment: Yes @Thracian I have

Comment: Your setup seems fine to me . Try invalidate and restart your Studio or rebuild the project . it should work fine .

Comment: It should work then. Clean build files and invalidate cache and restart

Comment: Share your `api` `interface` , did you use `Retrofit` until now?

Comment: @miladsalimi but the problem is still present when injecting retrofit I don't see how sharing my api interface will be of any help.

Comment: @ADM Tried that still not working

Comment: @ADM I tried writing the same code in java and it works for some reason

Comment: @AdityaKurkure I tried your code and it works fine for me.

Comment: @iamanbansal could it be the dependencies then?

Comment: I added the class path in project level gradle and the 2 plugins , the 2 dependencies in the app level gradle file. Also changed the compile options

Answer (score 2):

Try to change your code like this:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
Object RetrofitModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideRetrofit (gson: Gson): Retrofit{
       return Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("Base Url")
            .addConverterFactory(
                   GsonConverterFactory.create(GsonBuilder().create())
             )
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava3CallAdapterFactory.create()).build()
    }
}
```

Instead of creating class try to create object. Don't create Gson in seperate function. i have got this error too when i am using moshi converter.

Answer (score 0):

I think your Retrofit return Type is wrong. Try this (it worked for me):

```
@Singleton
@Provides
fun provideRetrofit (gson: Gson): Retrofit.Builder() {
   return Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("Base Url")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
        .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava3CallAdapterFactory.create())
}
```

EDIT: Oh and change `class RetrofitModule` to `object RetrofitModule`! Otherwise, the `@Provides` is never executed. And please bear in mind that you can use your retrofit only after `onCreate()`

Comment: Thanks but if the return type was wrong I don't think the could would have been executed (I still tried it and it didn't work). And it doesn't work with object either